# Can you cover an angel food cake with fondant?

Tags: baking, frosting

can anyone tell me if I can cover an angel food cake with fondant or is it too heavy for this sort of cake?
What is the best for this kind of cake...

Comment: I think you *can* cover an angel food cake with fondant, but it seems that it would clash. Angel food cake begs for a light glaze if anything.

Comment: @Jolenealaska I think people use a whipped cream topping sometimes... but, again, that's a very light frosting.

Comment: What do you mean by "What is the best for this kind of cake..."?

Comment: I would say a matter of taste, but most I think would side with a taste/style clash.  In the MidWest US I do know icing Angel food cakes is a bit more common than I see elsewhere, sometimes up to a fairly heavy buttercream icing, but I think fondant would still be beyond any I have seen.  If you want to, I would definitely roll it very thin, not use a heavy layer like modeling clay.

Answer (score 3):

Angel food cake has a very light and springy texture. It has no fat and so can sometimes feel more dry than other types of cake.

It is eaten precisely because it has a lighter, less rich, flavor. Toppings should accentuate this not detract. It's rare to see a rich buttercream frosting on an angel food cake, for example. Common toppings are whipped cream and fruit, a simple glaze, or just a dusting of powdered sugar.

Once cooled, an angel food cake would be able to support the weight of thinly rolled fondant but it is my opinion that it would not at all work with the simplicity of that cake. If you are going to eat the cake then you should use a lighter topping. If you aren't going to eat it then put your fondant on a cake that is less work to make.

Much of this information was written years ago in comments by Jolenealaska, Catija, and dlb.